# App not finding external service - why so?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

In App A, I have the following code to start a service in App B:

```
public void startAppBService() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.example.project.appBCommunicator");
    List<ResolveInfo> services = packageManager.queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
    Log.d("Services", Integer.toString(services.size()));
    if (services.size() > 0) {
        ResolveInfo service = services.get(0);

        serviceIntent.setClassName(service.serviceInfo.packageName, service.serviceInfo.name);
        serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.project.appBReceive");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("appAReceiver", resultReceiver);

        ComponentName cn = startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

I call this code in the `onCreate` method of App A.

In App B, I registered my IntentService in the manifest like this

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.project.appBCommunicator"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.project.appBReceive" />
        />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My code for my IntentService is this:

```
public class AppBCommunicator extends IntentService {

    public AppBCommunicator() {
        super("AppBCommunicator");
    }

    public AppBCommunicator(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ResultReceiver rec = intent.getParcelableExtra("appAReceiver");
        ResultReceiver sendingReceiver = receiverForSending(rec);
        String val = intent.getStringExtra("foo");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("resultValue", "My Result Value. Passed in: " + val);
        sendingReceiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
    }

    public static ResultReceiver receiverForSending(ResultReceiver actualReceiver) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        actualReceiver.writeToParcel(parcel,0);
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        ResultReceiver receiverForSending = ResultReceiver.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
        parcel.recycle();
        return receiverForSending;
    }
}
```

For some reason App A is not finding the IntentService of App B (`services.size()` returns 0).  Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Intent` is:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.example.project.appBCommunicator");
```

Here, your action string is `com.example.project.appBCommunicator`.

Your `<intent-filter>` is:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.project.appBReceive" />
    />
</intent-filter>
```

Here, your action string is `com.example.project.appBReceive`.

Your `Intent` does not match your `<intent-filter>`, because the action strings do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my fix was to delete my IntentService file and recreate it under a different name using the Android Studio auto-generate wizard instead of creating it manually.  I don't know why this made a difference, but it did.